# What does the JRE consist of?

Tags: java

i know that the JDK consists of all java packages .But what does the JRE consist of apart from java.exe ? I could understand the necessities of things in 'bin' folder in the JRE but what about the 'lib' folder ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this [JDK and JRE File Structure](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html) document from Sun's JDK documentation.

It specifically says the following about the `lib` directory:

> Code libraries, property settings, and resource files used by the Java runtime environment. For example:
>
> - rt.jar -- the bootstrap classes (the RunTime classes that comprise the Java platform's core API).
> - charsets.jar -- character conversion classes.
>
> Aside from the ext subdirectory (described below) there are several additional resource subdirectories not described here.

Answer (score 3):

JRE is composed of the JVM which is the runtime interpreter for the Java language, the Class Loader, Secure Execution Implementation classes,
Java APIs(core classes, SE classes) and the Java Web (Deployment) foundation which includes Java Web Start.

The lib part of JRE is Java's Library containing classes that lay the foundation for features like JavaBeans Components(JBCL) and Generic Collections(GCL).

Comment: I think you meant "The JVM is composed the the JRE", which is more accurate.

Comment: The JRE is an implementation of the JVM specification.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of it has the runtime support including standard class libraries.

Comment: what do you mean by "standard class libraries" - you mean the same thing that is in the java packages in jdk ?

Comment: yes, although there may be some differences as not all of those may be required at runtime. if you install the jre you will see it is missing the compiler etc, vs the jdk.

Comment: but i searched the entire folders of JRE but couldnt find any source code for java packages as that found in JDK .

Comment: oh so the jar files contain all the class files for java packages found in the sdk.isnt it frank ? thanks a  lot for your patient answers pal.

Comment: i think this is what you meant - "rt.jar" -- the bootstrap classes (the RunTime classes that comprise the Java platform's core API

Answer (score 0):

JRE is a Java Runtime Environment it is contains of set of libraries +other files that JVM uses runtime.JRE provides runtime environment for Java applications.JRE implementation of JVM.